# Используя pycountry получить названия стран

Tags: python, pandas, геолокация

Есть вот такой массив данных (это кусочек от столбца датафрейма).

```
                                time    latitude     longitude  depth   mag  place
0   1949-12-31 22:30:09.770000+00:00    34.191167   -117.522000 4.49    2.58    8km SSW of Lytle Creek, CA
1   1949-12-31 06:16:08.260000+00:00    35.859333   -117.650667 0.00    2.01    24km WNW of Searles Valley, CA
2   1949-12-30 23:14:21.690000+00:00    32.143333   -116.628833 6.00    3.30    28km N of El Sauzal, B.C., MX
3   1949-12-30 20:27:39.040000+00:00    33.856167   -118.089333 0.25    1.83    1km SSW of Artesia, CA
4   1949-12-30 11:13:51.930000+00:00    32.113000   -116.806333 6.00    3.02    16km SE of Primo Tapia, B.C., MX
```

Нужно перевести это все в название страны, например, CA - **Канада**, MX - **Мексика** и др. Пробовал `.split('; ')`, но не получается все собрать в один столбец. Начинает мешать Мексика, уходит в другой столбец. Из-за этого получается новый столбец с `None`. Другая трудность — это штаты. Я не понимаю как их соединить в одну США. Узнал в интернете про `pycountry`, но не смог реализовать решение. Дайте подсказку или хоть какой-нибудь пример.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob as gl
import pycountry as pc

list_of_files = gl.glob(files)

earthquakes = []
country = []

for i in range(len(list_of_files)):
    earthquakes.append(pd.read_csv(list_of_files[i], low_memory=False))

earthquakes = pd.concat(earthquakes).reset_index(drop=True)
earthquakes.time = pd.to_datetime(earthquakes.time)
earthquakes.latitude = pd.to_numeric(earthquakes.latitude)
earthquakes.longitude = pd.to_numeric(earthquakes.longitude)
earthquakes.place = earthquakes.place.apply(str)
earthquakes.drop(columns=['magType', 'magNst', 'gap', 'dmin', 'rms', 'net', 'id', 'nst', 'updated', 'type', 'horizontalError', 
                          'depthError', 'magError', 'status', 'locationSource', 'magSource'])

for i in range(len(earthquakes)):    
    country.append(earthquakes.place[i].split(', '))

country = pd.DataFrame(country)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: На выходе необходимо получить сводную таблицу. А на входе подаются следующие данные: 
```time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type,horizontalError,depthError,magError,magNst,status,locationSource,magSource```

***- это заголовки датафрейма***

```1949-12-31T22:30:09.770Z,34.1911667,-117.522,4.49,2.58,ml,7,117,0.2213,0.33,ci,ci3355511,2016-01-28T01:46:13.090Z,"8km SSW of Lytle Creek, CA",earthquake,0.83,2.79,0.117,6,reviewed,ci,ci```

***- это собственно строка из датафрейма***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для более точного определения страны можно воспользоваться "reverse geocoding", который позволяет определить страну, регион и город (если возможно) *по координатам*. Пример с использованием [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/release-0.96.2/):

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key="<your_api_key>")
>>> address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.reverse("40.752067, -73.977578")
>>> print address, latitude, longitude
77 East 42nd Street, New York, NY 10017, USA 40.7520802 -73.9775683
```

---

Мне не хотелось создавать `api_key`, поэтому я воспользовался оффлайновым сервисом [reverse_geocoder](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder) и функцией `alpha2_to_country_name` из соседнего ответа:

```
import reverse_geocoder as rgc
from functools import lru_cache

df["country"] = \
    [alpha2_to_country_name(r.get("cc"))
     for r in  rgc.search([tuple(x) for x in df[["latitude", "longitude"]].to_numpy()])]
```

результат:

```
In [485]: df[["place", "country"]]
Out[485]:
                              place        country
0        8km SSW of Lytle Creek, CA  United States
1    24km WNW of Searles Valley, CA  United States
2     28km N of El Sauzal, B.C., MX         Mexico
3            1km SSW of Artesia, CA  United States
4  16km SE of Primo Tapia, B.C., MX         Mexico
```

Comment: Второй способ очень помог (я про reverse_geocoder). Но вот gettext не смог перевести ***Cabo Verde***, ***Czechia***, ***Eswatini*** и ***North*** ***Macedonia***, но это пустяки. reverse_geocoder удивил. 3822907 строк уместились в 230 строк сводной таблицы. Объявляю вопрос ***решенным***.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pycountry
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(256)
def alpha2_to_country_name(code):
    if not isinstance(code, str):
        return np.nan
    code = code.strip()
    if not code or len(code) != 2:
        return np.nan
    r = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=code)
    if not r:
        return np.nan
    return r.name
```

пример использования:

```
df.loc[:, "country"] = df["place"].str.extract(r",\s*(\w+)$")[0].dropna().map(alpha2_to_country_name)
```

результат:

```
In [424]: df
Out[424]:
                              time   latitude   longitude  depth   mag                             place country
0 1949-12-31 22:30:09.770000+00:00  34.191167 -117.522000   4.49  2.58        8km SSW of Lytle Creek, CA  Canada
1 1949-12-31 06:16:08.260000+00:00  35.859333 -117.650667   0.00  2.01    24km WNW of Searles Valley, CA  Canada
2 1949-12-30 23:14:21.690000+00:00  32.143333 -116.628833   6.00  3.30     28km N of El Sauzal, B.C., MX  Mexico
3 1949-12-30 20:27:39.040000+00:00  33.856167 -118.089333   0.25  1.83            1km SSW of Artesia, CA  Canada
4 1949-12-30 11:13:51.930000+00:00  32.113000 -116.806333   6.00  3.02  16km SE of Primo Tapia, B.C., MX  Mexico
```

эффективность кеша функции:

```
In [425]: alpha2_to_country_name.cache_info()
Out[425]: CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=2, maxsize=256, currsize=2)
```

PS функция `alpha2_to_country_name` реально отработает столько раз сколько у вас уникальных непустых кодов стран. Для повторяющихся кодов стран - результат будет взят из кеша. Для большого набора данных это может ускорить обработку на порядки.

---

Модуль [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) также умеет переводить названия стран на разные языки при помощи модуля [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html):

```
import gettext

ru_countries = gettext.translation('iso3166', pycountry.LOCALES_DIR, languages=['ru'])
ru_countries.install()

df.loc[:, "country_rus"] = df["country"].dropna().map(_)
```

результат:

```
In [441]: df.filter(regex="(?:country|place)")
Out[441]:
                              place country country_rus
0        8km SSW of Lytle Creek, CA  Canada      Канада
1    24km WNW of Searles Valley, CA  Canada      Канада
2     28km N of El Sauzal, B.C., MX  Mexico     Мексика
3            1km SSW of Artesia, CA  Canada      Канада
4  16km SE of Primo Tapia, B.C., MX  Mexico     Мексика
```

Comment: В моем массиве данных, некоторые страны обозначены кодом, например, CA, US, но есть и страны, которые не имеют такого обозначения, например Россия -Russia, Таджикистан, Tajikista, Uzbekistan. Почти все страны СНГ обозначены их собственным наименованием. Правильно понимаю, Вы предлагаете использовать рекурсию, чтобы извлечь названия и коды стран?

Comment: @aufloren, я не увидел в вашем "воспроизводимом" примере данных в вопросе ни одного такого обозначения. Я не предлагаю использовать рекурсию - я предлагаю расшифровать коды стран в их названия, используя библиотеку `pycountry`. PS на каком языке вы хотите получить названия стран - на английском или на русском?

Comment: Можно на английском, но если найду способ получить на русском, тогда - русский. Скорее всего воспользуюсь gettext